# Integrating SQL Table Data into SalesForce Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, bulk-api

Does anyone know whether it is possible to migrate **SQL** Table data into Salesforce custom object?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You'll need to add more details of what you've already researched yourself if you expect a usefull answer. Currently your question is very high level, the answer is "yes", but i imagine you'd like to more than that.

Comment: Right now I'm researching on the usage of Bulk API since it can easily process the bulk of records as 'Batch' with the help of Jobs. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: There is a variety of methods, but dataloader or the bulk api is a good point to start. Do you already have the datamodel mapped to custom objects in salesforce, you may need to consider mappings or data transformations too. There are many aspects that might need to be taken into account, each worth of their own questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of applications out there to do this too (for a fee of course).  I can personally vouch for DB/Amp Pro - pretty easy to set up if you're familiar with SQL Server and not too expensive compared to some of the competitors.  But there are a lot to choose from if you can afford to spend money on it and want to avoid the hassle of developing from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MySQL or Postgres, another option is [cloudconnect.com](http://cloudconnect.com).  Cloudconnect automatically syncs salesforce objects into either Postgres or Mysql, and maintains the sync in both directions, without any scripts or coding.  There is a free trial available on the website.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution reusing [Wade](http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/05/uploading-an-attachment-to-salesforce-with-the-soap-and-rest-apis/)'s code. I actually tested this with several SQL tables with hundreds of columns. it did the trick. I hope it works for you

download C# code 
https://github.com/zamoradev/Trinity

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail on how to do this?

Comment: Sure! you download the app and open it with visual studio 2013 (you can use the express version which is free), then in the app.config you need to add the information regarding: the DATASOURCE, THE SERVER NAME, THE TABLE (from sql you want to migrate), and also add your salesforce credentials on USERNAME, PASSWORD and ORG ID. once you setup all that information, the run the program (this app works with windows authentication on the database, if you don't have windows auth, the you need to modify the connection string to add your credentials)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to migrate data from your SQL table to Salesforce, if your database server is SQL Server. There are at least two products that can accomplish this.

- [DbAmp](http://www.forceamp.com/) - DbAmp exposes Salesforce as another database through ODBC driver - so your write integrations using regular SQL. DbAmp supports both bulk/batch API - Cost of DbAmp is around $1295
- [Pragmatic Works Task Factory](http://www.pragmaticworks.com/Products/Task-Factory.aspx) - Cost of Task Factory is $0/$995/$1495. The community edition doesn't support Salesforce connector, but other two editions does.

With both these products, if you know SQL you can easily write SQL scripts/SSIS jobs to synchronize the data between SQL server and Salesforce. I have personally worked with DbAmp and for this cost, it is a no brainer. The support is also very good.

Every other integration tool like Boomi, Informatica Cloud, Jitterbit, Snaplogic, Cast Iron can do this as well. But the cost and the learning curve is too high.